Material Preview Shader Issue
I am using Blender for basic architectural visualization. I have been using it form 2.8 version. There is a strange problem with 4.2.1, I see strange patterns in all the materials, even simple materials. I have attached the screenshot of it. In rendering there is no issue, it renders perfectly. The issue is only in the viewport, in Material Preview Shader. I have been using the same PC for last 2 years. In the earlier versions i did not have this issue. This PC has a inbuilt graphics card - Ryzen 5 5600G Processer, Windows 11. I tried in another PC also with Ryzen 5 5600G Processer. I would be very thankful if any one can help me understand and solve the issue.

Update your graphics drivers

One of the files which I randomly adjusted some settings do not have the problem. I could find what worked. Some settings from 4.1 to 4.2 is giving this issue.
